# How can I check whether a string array includes a specified string in `jq`?

Tags: shell, jq

I have an array of string in json format. I'd like to check whether it includes a specific string value.

I have tried to use `contains`:

```
echo '["aa", "bb", "cc"]' |jq '. | contains(["aa"])'
> true
```

it works but it also return true for a partial match:

```
echo '["aa", "bb", "cc"]' |jq '. | contains(["a"])'
> true
```

how can I find the exact match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex with a word boundary:

```bash
$ echo '["aa", "bb", "cc"]' | jq -r '.[] | test(["\\baa\\b"]) | tostring | select(. == "true")'
true

$ echo '["aa", "bb", "cc"]' | jq -r '.[] | test(["\\ba\\b"]) | tostring | select(. == "true")'
```